# Trying to use boolean logic within Application.WorksheetFunction.MATCH and getting Type Mismatch error

Tags: indexing, match, boolean-logic, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet function that is working perfectly fine in the worksheet, however, when I try to reproduce it in a macro I am receiving a Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch.  The function in the worksheet is:

=INDEX(TBQA[Question],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(TBQA[Answer]=TBQA[@Answer],0),0))

The table I am drawing the values from is named "TBQA".  The two columns I am trying to refer to in part of the macro are "Question" and "Answer".  I have a UserForm ComboBox that I am using as the comparison reference source named "TBABox" and when I click a button, I want to index the value in the "Question" column that matches the answer in the "Answer" column (which is the source for the ComboBox dropdown values).

```
Private Sub ShowMeQues_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Information")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Resource")

MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws1.Range("TBQA[Question]"), _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("TRUE", _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws1.Range("TBQA[Answer]") = TBABox.Value, 0), 0))

End Sub
```

I believe the issue is occurring when I am trying to get a "TRUE" value where the ws1.Range("TBQA[Answer]") = TBABox.Value, but I could be wrong.  Please help.  I feel like it is a simple fix that I am just overlooking, but I have been searching the internet to find out a resolution to no avail.  Any suggestions welcome.  THANK YOU!!! :)

Comment: I think "TRUE" is a string. You are trying to match boolean true, which (if I remember correctly) in vba is 1.

Comment: I tried changing the "TRUE" to "True", True, 1, and "1". I achieve the same error each time unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, I am not so familiar with putting tables in worksheet functions in vba. Have you tried recording a macro while you enter the formula (to see the generated code)? Sometimes it is enough to copy the formula to a new cell, with the macro recorder on, then see what you get...

Comment: That is a good idea. I have actually not tried that. I will give that a go and share any updates if I get it figured out. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the macro that is recorded is just a "formulaR1C1 = the formula I posted in the original post". It does not transform it into an Application.WorksheetFunction code format.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by taking another route!  My main goal was to bypass the 255 Character limit set by VBA with the MATCH function.  Please see my other post for the resolution that I came up with.  Thank you for your help!!!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72582313/10443879