# Bypass 255 character limit of Index MATCH Function with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

My reference is a table named "TBQA" with column headers "Question" and "Answer".  I have used the "Answer" column as a RowSource in a UserForm ComboBox drop-down.  I am trying to use the selection in this UserForm drop-down in an Index Match function via VBA.  Unfortunately, some of my selections in the drop-down surpass the 255 character limit.

I have successfully bypassed the 255 character limit for the MATCH function in the worksheet, however, I cannot replicate it using VBA.  The worksheet function looks like this:

```
=INDEX(TBQA[Question],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(TBQA[Answer]=TBQA[@Answer],0),0))
```

Here is my code:

```
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws1.Range("TBQA[Question]"), _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(True, _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(TBABox.Value = ws1.Range("TBQA[Answer]"), 0), 0))
```

I am receiving the Type Mismatch error code.  It would seem that it is a simple correction.  I am guessing that if I can get it to work in the worksheet I can get VBA to do the same.  PLEASE HELP!!!  Thank you GREATLY in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest version of Excel, you can use the XMATCH function.  It doesn't have the 255 character limit.

```
With Application
    MsgBox .Index(ws1.Range("TBQA[Question]"), .XMatch(TBABox.Value, ws1.Range("TBQA[Answer]")))
End With
```

Otherwise, try the following formula instead...

```
With Application
    MsgBox .Index(ws1.Range("TBQA[Question]"), Evaluate("MATCH(TRUE," & ws1.Range("TBQA[Answer]").Address(, , , True) & "=" & TBABox.Value & ",0)"))
End With
```

However, if your combobox contains a text value instead of a number, you'll need to enclose its value within quotes...

```
With Application
    MsgBox .Index(ws1.Range("TBQA[Question]"), Evaluate("MATCH(TRUE," & ws1.Range("TBQA[Answer]").Address(, , , True) & "=""" & TBABox.Value & """,0)"))
End With
```

Comment: I am using Excel 2016 so I tried using the second code and achieved the error; "Compile Error: Method or data member not found" and it highlights the ".Address" following "TBABox".

Comment: That works perfectly, however, I am running into the issue of a 255 character limit again.  The function works flawlessly in the worksheet.  I believe there is a 255 character limit on the Evaluate function which brings me back to the same issue I was having before.  I just need to somehow harness the power of the formula in the worksheet and directly translate it to VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out!!!  I created a new table column titled "AbbAns" to represent the abbreviated answers.  In this column I used the formula:

`=LEFT([@Answer],255)`

Then, instead of referencing the "Answer" column in the code I just reference the "AbbAns" column.  The final code that works is this:

```
Private Sub ShowMeQues_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Information")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Resource")
   
Set Question = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws1.Range("TBQA[Question]"), _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Left(TBABox.Value, 255), ws1.Range("TBQA[AbbAns]"), 0))

MsgBox Question

End Sub
```

This may not be the easiest way to do it, but IT WORKS!!!

Comment: Actually, I think it's an excellent workaround, and it's probably more efficient.  I gave it a +1.